# Caps lock do not trigger `keyup` event on mac in Chrome or Safari

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome, safari

```
window.addEventListener('keyup',()=>{console.log('up')})
```

`caps lock` key can't trigger `keyup` event on mac in Chrome and Safari.
Other keys like 'a', 'b' will trigger the event.
It's ok on my partner's window's chrome computer.

MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Chrome 74.0.3729.131 X64

PS.

I think my Chinese language input may cause this. If I close `Use caps lock to switch 'ABC' input mode`(Which I translated) in keyboard settings. It will be triggered when I pressed the key twice. I think this is not a expected behavior.

Comment: Caps lock should trigger all keyboard events, including `keyup`. There's nothing wrong with the code (that I can see). Consider restarting chrome, the computer, and maybe even reinstalling Chrome.

Comment: see the `console` it seems like okay . It should be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not resolved, submitted a report to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into this , it will alert `20` as [keyCode](http://www.foreui.com/articles/Key_Code_Table.htm)

```js
var test = document.getElementById('test');
test.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  alert(e.which);
});
   // test.addEventListener('keyup',()=>{console.log('up')}) will also works
```

```html
<input type="text" id="test" placeholder="enter text">
```

Comment: No errors. I think the event just have not been triggered.

Comment: I think my Chinese language input may cause this. If I close `Use caps lock to switch 'ABC' input mode`(Which I translated). It will be triggered when I press the key twice. I think this is not a expected behavior.